# State classes in Apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stateful

I am approaching the Dataflow and Apache Beam world and I have some questions about stateful processing and some classes implementation.

In particular, I am wondering what are the differences between [SetStateSpec](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/userstate.html#SetStateSpec) and [BagStateSpec](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/userstate.html#BagStateSpec).
Indeed, in https://datacraftacademy.com/apache-beam-python-stateful-processing/ it looks like they are the same thing, but I am still unsure about that.

Moreover, I am looking for the source code of these [classes](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/1ffda469fb1d9ca128f36261be954cfcf26e5b4e/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/userstate.py#L91), but I can't retrive where 'beam_runner_api_pb2' points to and where it is implemented.

Furthermore, I have an unclear picture about [AccumulatingRuntimeState](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/userstate.html#AccumulatingRuntimeState) and all the classes that inherites from it (BagRuntimeState, SetRuntimeState, CombiningValueRuntimeState). Are these classes not implemented in the python SDK or am I missing something? Eventually, what are the differences between these classes and the non-Runtime states (e.g. SetStateSpec) and what different use cases are they used for?

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

##### Runtime vs non-runtime classes

The `SetStateSpec`, `BagStateSpec`, are non-runtime specs used to let the SDK know about state to be kept by Beam.

The runtime classes (e.g. `SetRuntimeState` and others) are the classes that implement the runtime behavior for the state handlers.

From the example in the blog post:

```
class MyDoFn(DoFn):
    # This is a non-runtime spec. It can be BagStateSpec, SetStateSpec, etc.
    INDEX_STATE = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec(
        name='index', coder=VarIntCoder())

    def process(self, element, index=beam.DoFn.StateParam(INDEX_STATE)):
        # When we call `process`, the `index` variable actually holds a
        # runtime state object.
        assert isinstance(index, ReadModifyWriteRuntimeState)  # This assert works 
fine
        current_index = index.read() or 0
        yield current_index, element
        index.write(current_index + 1)
```

##### On `SetStateSpec` vs `BagStateSpec`

For `SetStateSpec` and `BagStateSpec`, they implement a similar kind of state, but `BagStateSpec` defines **something like a list**, while `SetStateSpec` defines **something like a set**. This means that BagStateSpec can hold multiple equal elements, while `SetStateSpec` will only hold one instance of any given object.

##### On `AccumulatingRuntimeState` and its classes

The code that you found are the interfaces to be implemented by the runner that Beam is using. For example, [you can find the Direct runner implementation here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4f1f1c11268d18d2045723f51915210fbca1bdd9/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_userstate.py#L62-L193).